# kernel is killing all the processes

Tags: linux, centos

One of my cent os 6.7 (2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64) virtual machine linux killing all the processes, not only application but also cron, auditd, httpd and mysql.
When I query for status it states pid file exists but service is dead. This server is sql node of mysql cluster. It is happening frequently after server reboot and after two three times its started working properly. I have enabled audit log and below is the log from messages

```
kernel: audit: *NO* daemon at audit_pid=17901
kernel: audit: audit_lost=89 audit_rate_limit=0 audit_backlog_limit=320
kernel: audit: auditd dissapeared
kernel: type=1318 audit(1488753001.130:770): opid=19004 oauid=0 ouid=0 oses=51 ocomm="callapi.sh"
kernel: type=1300 audit(1488753001.130:771): arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=yes exit=0 a0=4a52 a1=9 a2=9 a3=4a52 items=0 ppid=19009 pid=19032 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=49 comm="kill" exe="/bin/kill" key="teste_kill"
kernel: type=1318 audit(1488753001.130:771): opid=19026 oauid=0 ouid=0 oses=51 ocomm="callapi.sh"
kernel: type=1300 audit(1488753001.130:772): arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=yes exit=0 a0=46be a1=9 a2=9 a3=46be items=0 ppid=19009 pid=19032 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=49 comm="kill" exe="/bin/kill" key="teste_kill"
kernel: type=1318 audit(1488753001.130:772): opid=18110 oauid=0 ouid=0 oses=44 ocomm="crond" type=1300 audit(1488753001.130:773): arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=yes exit=0 a0=4a34 a1=9 a2=9 a3=4a34 items=0 ppid=19009 pid=19032 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=49 comm="kill" exe="/bin/kill" key="teste_kill"
kernel: type=1318 audit(1488753001.130:773): opid=18996 oauid=0 ouid=0 oses=50 ocomm="crond"
init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process (14691) killed by KILL signal
init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process ended, respawning
init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (14693) killed by KILL signal
init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process ended, respawning
init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (14694) killed by KILL signal
init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process ended, respawning
init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (14695) killed by KILL signal
init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process ended, respawning
init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (14696) killed by KILL signal
init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process ended, respawning
kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
kernel: type=1318 audit(1488753001.130:773): opid=18996 oauid=0 ouid=0 oses=50 ocomm="crond"
kernel: type=1300 audit(1488753001.130:774): arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=yes exit=0 a0=4a3b a1=9 a2=9 a3=4a3b items=0 ppid=19009 pid=19032 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=49 comm="kill" exe="/bin/kill" key="teste_kill"
kernel: type=1300 audit(1488754808.281:1069): arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=no exit=-3 a0=4673 a1=0 a2=0 a3=4673 items=0 ppid=1 pid=20268 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=54 comm="java" exe="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111.x86_64/jre/bin/java" key="teste_kill"
```

Below is the sar report of memory.

01:20:01 AM  10535308   5798748     35.50    449520   2901344   3523388     17.16
01:30:01 AM  10529272   5804784     35.54    449520   2902444   3521484     17.15
01:40:01 AM  10524924   5809132     35.56    449520   2903496   3521852     17.16
Average:     10531009   5803047     35.53    449520   2897895   3518261     17.14

01:58:39 AM       LINUX RESTART

07:30:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit
02:10:01 AM  16057300    276756      1.69     30220     58348    187056      0.91
02:20:01 AM  16057316    276740      1.69     30332     58364    187056      0.91
02:30:01 AM  16057192    276864      1.70     30452     58372    187288      0.91

Answer (score 0):

When the kernel starts killing seemingly random processes, it's usually caused by the system running out of memory (both RAM and swap).

Check your VM's memory status with `free -h`, then adjust as necessary.

Comment: I have added servers to new relic monitoring and there is nothing abnormal with server at the time of issue.